# Get duplicate multi-d array value

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to get all the duplicate values from an array, but all i see here is how to remove them, is there any way in retrieving only the duplicates and showing how many times they have duplicated?

For example

```
array(
  array(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  array(6,5,4,3,2,1),
  array(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  array(3,4,8,4,3,1),
  array(6,5,4,3,2,1),
)
```

I want to have like
array(1,2,3,4,5,6) duplicated 2 times
and 
array(6,5,4,3,2,1) also duplicated 2 times

Those that are not duplicated will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://eval.in/702484)

```
foreach($array as $arr)
{
  $o[implode(',', $arr)][] = 1;
}
array_walk($o, function($v, $k){echo $k.':'.count($v);});
```