# Count duplicate values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to count the same values in multidimensional array and remove the duplicates.

My array:

```
$r = [
    ['a','b'],
    ['a','b'],
    ['c','d'],
    ['c','d'],
    ['c','d'],
    ['e','f'],
];
```

Need to output:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => b
        [1] => 2 // Result
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => d
        [1] => 3 // Result
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => e
        [1] => f
        [1] => 1 // Result
    )
```

I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: I have tried but to no avail

Comment: "*What*" have you tried, exactly? Share the code you've got so far, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41275759/6521116

Comment: I don't think your output can with the same key 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$r = [
    ['a','b'],
    ['a','b'],
    ['c','d'],
    ['c','d'],
    ['c','d'],
    ['e','f'],
];
foreach($r as $arr)
{
  $o[implode(',', $arr)][] = 1;
}
$output = [];
array_walk($o, function($v, $k) use(&$output){
    $output[] = array_merge(explode(',', $k), [count($v)]);
});
var_dump($output);
```

and the output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [2]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "d"
    [2]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "e"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "f"
    [2]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $result1 as $key ):
    $o[implode(', ', $key)][] = null;
     foreach ($o as $key1) {
        $g[implode(', ', $key)] = count($key1);
    }
endforeach;
print_r($g);
```